# dagger test component not being generated when the project contains multiple android modules

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

```
Android Studio 3.4
kotlin 1.3.0
dagger 2.21
```

I have a project that has a `presentation` and `data` module. And I am trying to create the test component in the data module. I can generate the component for the presentation module. I am using kotlin-kts for the gradle build.

For the presentation moudle I have the following `build.gradle.kts`

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    kotlin("android")
    kotlin("kapt")
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion(Versions.compileSdkVersion)

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "nz.org.westforce.mobileui"
        minSdkVersion(Versions.minSdkVersion)
        targetSdkVersion(Versions.targetSdkVersion)
        versionCode = Versions.versionCode
        versionName = Versions.versionName

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        getByName("release") {
            isMinifyEnabled = true
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(Libraries.appCompat)
    implementation(Libraries.kotlinStdlib)
    implementation(Libraries.daggerAndroid)
    implementation(Libraries.daggerSupport)
    kapt(Libraries.daggerCompiler)
    kapt(Libraries.daggerProcessor)

    androidTestImplementation(TestLibraries.runner)
    androidTestImplementation(TestLibraries.espressoCore)

    testImplementation(TestLibraries.junit)
    testImplementation(Libraries.daggerAndroid)
    testImplementation(Libraries.daggerSupport)

    kaptTest(Libraries.daggerCompiler)
    kaptTest(Libraries.daggerProcessor)

    implementation(project(":data"))
}
```

For the presentation module I have the following Application:

```
class WestforceCreditUnionMobileuiApplication
    : Application(), HasActivityInjector {

    @Inject
    lateinit var dispatchingAndroidActivityInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity>

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        DaggerWestforceCreditUnionMobileuiComponent.builder()
            .application(this)
            .build()
            .inject(this)
    }

    override fun activityInjector(): AndroidInjector<Activity> =
        dispatchingAndroidActivityInjector
}
```

The Component

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class])
interface WestforceCreditUnionMobileuiComponent {
    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: WestforceCreditUnionMobileuiApplication): Builder

        fun build(): WestforceCreditUnionMobileuiComponent
    }

    fun inject(application: WestforceCreditUnionMobileuiApplication)
}
```

The above is working and the `DaggerWestforceCreditUnionMobileuiComponent` is generated

Now in my `data` module I can trying to create a test component but dagger doesn't generate the test component classes.

I have the following test component in `java/test/package/di` directory

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [TestNetworkModule::class])
interface TestWestforceCeditUnionComponent {
    fun inject(webServicesImpTest: WebServicesImpTest)
}
```

And in my test class:

```
class WebServicesImpTest {

    @Inject
    private lateinit var webServicesImp: WebServicesImp

    @Test
    fun setUp() {
        /* the DaggerTestWestforceCreditUnionComponent is not generated */
    }
}
```

I haven't specified the modules here as it will inflate the code here too much.

For my build.gradle.kts in the data module:

```
import org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.implementation

plugins {
    id("com.android.library")
    id("kotlin-android")
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion(Versions.compileSdkVersion)

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion(Versions.minSdkVersion)
        targetSdkVersion(Versions.targetSdkVersion)
        versionCode = Versions.versionCode
        versionName = Versions.versionName

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        getByName("release") {
            isMinifyEnabled = true
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(Libraries.kotlinStdlib)
    implementation(Libraries.appCompat)
    implementation(Libraries.daggerAndroid)
    implementation(Libraries.daggerSupport)
    kapt(Libraries.daggerCompiler)
    kapt(Libraries.daggerProcessor)

    testImplementation(TestLibraries.junit)
    testImplementation(TestLibraries.assertJ)
    testImplementation(TestLibraries.mockitoKotlin)

    testImplementation(Libraries.daggerAndroid)
    testImplementation(Libraries.daggerSupport)
    kaptTest(Libraries.daggerCompiler)
    kaptTest(Libraries.daggerProcessor)
}
```

I am using the following dagger.android dependencies:

```
  const val daggerAndroid = "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:${Versions.daggerAndroidVersion}"
  const val daggerCompiler = "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:${Versions.daggerAndroidVersion}"
  const val daggerProcessor = "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:${Versions.daggerAndroidVersion}"
  const val daggerSupport = "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:${Versions.daggerAndroidVersion}"
```

I have tried rebuilding the project and trying running the following task `compileDebugUnitTestSources`

Everything builds successfully,

One think I am thinking about as I am using different android modules, maybe the data module cannot see the `WestforceCreditUnionMobileuiApplication` in the presentation module.

Many thanks for any suggestions

Comment: Can you try to run `assembleAndroidTest `

Comment: I have actually tried that already. I think the problem is because I have 2 android modules `presentation` and `data` The Application is in the presentation and maybe the `data` module cannot see that.

Comment: Where do you place this `TestWestforceCeditUnionComponent`?

Comment: Can you extract a simple setup to github and share a link?

Comment: @azizbekian The repo is here: https://github.com/steve1rm/WestcreditUnion. Thanks for your help again. The issue is related to the `data` module. I am trying to create the dagger component in the `WebServicesImpTest.kt` However, dagger does not generate the component. I think its because the application is in the `mobileui` module. Once again, thanks for your review.

Comment: @azizbekian I have added you as a `Collaborator` to that repo.

Comment: @ant2009, I've downloaded Android Studio 3.4 RC2, but I'm unable to import the project (`master` branch). Can you tell what I'm missing in your setup? What's the problem with my import?

Comment: @azizbekian I am using AS 3.4 RC2 as well. I have just create a clean directory on my local and cloned that repo. Rather than importing the project I did the following `open an existing android studio project`  And selecting the root `build.gradle.kts`

Comment: @azizbekian the project opened ok and I was able to build it. The project uses kotlin scripts for the gradle build

Comment: @ant2009, I'm sorry that I couldn't help. As long as Dmide posted an answer it's obvious that he was able to build the project, hence the problem is in my setup. Hope Dmide's solution works for you.

Comment: @azizbekian thanks for your time and help. I will check Dmide solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to add

```
kotlin("kapt")
```

to `plugins` section in `:data` module build.gradle.kts.

Gradle then proceeds with errors about missing `@Provides` for your `WebServicesImp`. Also you should fix the missing `Context` provider, in my example I just removed the `Context` use. This should be added to `TestNetworkModule`:

```
@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideRetrofit(okHttpClient: OkHttpClient): Retrofit {
    return Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("http://www.holidaywebservice.com")
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.createNonStrict(Persister(AnnotationStrategy())))
        .build()
}
@Reusable
@Provides
fun provideWebServices(retrofit: Retrofit): WebServices {
    return retrofit.create(WebServices::class.java)
}

@Reusable
@Provides
fun provideWebServicesImp(webServices : WebServices): WebServicesImp {
    return WebServicesImp(webServices)
}
```

After that `DaggerTestWestforceCeditUnionComponent` was successfully generated.

Comment: Thanks, that worked, thanks for the help. `plugins {
    id("com.android.library")
    id("kotlin-android")
    kotlin("android")
    kotlin("kapt")
}` I have added above plugins. I have some confusion about those. Can you explain about them?

Comment: kotlin("android") enables kotlin support in this module (id("kotlin-android") is the same but different method), kotlin("kapt") enables annotation processing in this module, which is requred for dagger to work.